# Add .stop(false, true) to more/all animations in a single line

Tags: jquery, animation

Is there a way to apply a `.stop(false,true)` to all the animations in a single blow?

Say, in my global.js I want all `.animate`, `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to have `.stop(false, true)` without actually having to white it to each of these animations.

Is there like a line of code (or multiple) that can be added at the beginning of the document that will add it automatically without it actually being in front of each animation?

Instead of :

```
$('#').stop(false, true).animate({
});
$('.x').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
$('.y').stop(false, true).fadeOut();
$('.z').stop(false, true).fadeIn();
```

Something like :

```
$wizard_stuff(animate, fadeIn, fadeOut).stop(false, true);
$('#').animate({
});
$('.x').fadeIn();
$('.y').fadeOut();
$('.z').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jq pseudo selector [:animated](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/):

```
$(':animated').stop(false, true);
```

> **Description:** Select all elements that are in the progress of an
>   animation at the time the selector is run.

Comment: I believe this will do the job nicely, thank you! I was just hoping for an all jquery way to do it in case I wanted to affect other things in one go.

Comment: @Alin What kind of other thing you would want to affect? Anyway, because any jq animation method internally calls `$.fn.animate`, you could just extend it, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/7cmnuzfr/

Comment: Uuu that fiddle is good, i like that :) in fact, this is exactly what I needed/hoped of finding.

Comment: But depending what you are looking for, i guess you'd have better to use `$(':animated').stop(false, true).doSomething();` or use a loop on set (still depending what you are looking for): `$(':animated').each(function(){...});`

Comment: I don't have need for '.each' in this case, I simply needed a way to affect all the animations in my document with .stop(false, true); since I realized I ended up using it at most of them and it would make the page harder to read + I also wanted to shorten the code. Both :animated and extending the $.fn.animate do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a function and just call that in your scripts whenever you need. You may or may not need to add parameters depending on if you will need to stop the animation on the same elements or selector everytime. For instance:

```
function stopAnimations() {
  $('#, .x, .y, .z').stop(false, true);
}

function startAnimations() {
  $('#').animate({
  });
  $('.x, .z').fadeIn();
  $('.y').fadeOut();
}
```

And then in other parts of your scripts you can just call `startAnimations()`. Is that something along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello, I'm gonna tell you what I also told Roy : The fadeIn() fadeOut() in my example is just for show, in the real code each of them is triggered by something else. Calling .stop on all the elements would get hard to follow if there area more animations with longer class/ID names and so on. I hoped I could call stop directly on the method.